# How to configure Slow Start Duration in ansible for elb_target_group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-elb

How can I configure the slow start duration as can be done in the AWS console of the load balancer target group in **ansible**?

I am currently using the **elb target group module** from ansible:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/elb_target_group_module.html

And I want to set the **slow start** as described here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_en/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html#slow-start-mode

For example:

```
# Create a target group with instance targets
- elb_target_group:
    name: mytargetgroup
    protocol: http
    port: 81
    vpc_id: vpc-01234567
    slow_start_duration: 30
    health_check_path: /
    successful_response_codes: "200,250-260"
    targets:
      - Id: i-01234567
        Port: 80
      - Id: i-98765432
        Port: 80
    state: present
    wait_timeout: 200
    wait: True
```

Answer (score 0):

Go in your Target Group, Description tab, scroll down: **Edit attributes**. There you'll have *Slow start duration*.

Comment: yes, this I can do but I want to do that automatically with ansible.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Don't know. I could share a CloudFormation snippet, but I don't automate with Ansible. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the duration value as a variable in your playbook and use it while executing the playbook.

Comment: Kanthi, could you please provide an example?